# Find the trigonometric sum $S = \cos(2\pi/13) + \cos(6\pi/13) + \cos(8\pi/13)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the sum $S = \cos(2\pi/13) + \cos(6\pi/13) + \cos(8\pi/13)$

I have been thinking to multiply both sides by $2\sin(2\pi/13)$ or something else, but I haven't found a solution. Please a hint!

Comment: middle term \cos(5\pi/13) ?

Comment: its cos(6pi/13)

Comment: 0.65138 numerical value, may be has no closed form

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Group first and third, sum of 2 cosines. Treat the middle term as double angle, simplify them taking common factor out.

Comment: idk, I'm stuck after factorizing